Details ejs not working after database query
I have  a context in node.js called Blog which displays the blogs which  users have inputed to the database on one webpage.  I then have a method which after a user clicks on the  blog then tries  to display a webpage with just the one blog entry. It queries by the ID of the blog post here is the code in the app.js file.
        const id = req.params.id;
        console.log(id); 
        Blog.findById(id)
            .then(result => {
                res.render('details', { title: 'Blog details ', blog: result }); 
            })
            .catch(err  => {
                console.log(err); 
            });
    });

Here is the details.ejs file which is supposed to output the blog post selected after the database query. The code finds the database ID as this in url header in chrome but the details page always shows as error 404. Please help
<html lang="en">
<%- include("./partials/head.ejs") %>

<body>
  <%- include("./partials/nav.ejs") %>
  <div class="details content">
      <h2><%= blog._id.title %></h2>
    <div class="content">
      <p><%= blog._id.body %></p>
     </div> 
      <a class="delete" data-doc="<%= blog._id %>">delete</a>
   </div>
    
  <%- include("./partials/footer.ejs") %>
</body>
</html>



First check that what  does console.log(result) prints? Have you properly setup view to serve .ejs template?

Could you provide more code of your app.js. Especially the (whole) snippets that handle everything from the point of clicking on a specific blog until the render.
And what exactly do you mean with The code finds the database ID as this in url header? Is the id in the URL, or in the header of the response, or something else? I can just assume you mean the lines in the snippet of app.js you shared that prints the query parameter id?

The id of the chosen blog
